# How to dump ARM-coprocessor registers using gdb?

Tags: debugging, gdb, arm

Is there a way to dump the co-processor registers of ARM (specifically CP15 sctlr) from gdb ? I am using toolchain from code-sourcery (arm-none-linux-gnueabi-) and debugging linux running on QEMU.

One way could be to dump the used GPR before/after the mcr/mrc instructions. Is there another way ?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, GDB/ARM won't be able to show this information ... but debugging `qemu` might help you (assuming that you can compile/debug qemu with its debug information):

1. Attach GDB (i686 certain, but not ARM) to your `qemu` process
2. Take a look at this file : [qemu/target-arm/cpu.h](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/qemu.git/tree/target-arm/cpu.h)
3. Inspect something like `env->cp15` or `gdbserver_state->g_cpu->cp15` * :

   ```
   struct {
   uint32_t c0_cachetype;
   uint32_t c0_ccsid[16]; /* Cache size.  */
   uint32_t c0_clid; /* Cache level.  */
   uint32_t c0_cssel; /* Cache size selection.  */
   uint32_t c0_c1[8]; /* Feature registers.  */
   uint32_t c0_c2[8]; /* Instruction set registers.  */
   uint32_t c1_sys; /* System control register.  */
   uint32_t c1_coproc; /* Coprocessor access register.  */
   uint32_t c1_xscaleauxcr; /* XScale auxiliary control register.  */
   uint32_t c2_base0; /* MMU translation table base 0.  */
   uint32_t c2_base1; /* MMU translation table base 1.  */
   uint32_t c2_control; /* MMU translation table base control.  */
   uint32_t c2_mask; /* MMU translation table base selection mask.  */
   uint32_t c2_base_mask; /* MMU translation table base 0 mask. */
   uint32_t c2_data; /* MPU data cachable bits.  */
   uint32_t c2_insn; /* MPU instruction cachable bits.  */
   uint32_t c3; /* MMU domain access control register
                   MPU write buffer control.  */
   uint32_t c5_insn; /* Fault status registers.  */
   uint32_t c5_data;
   uint32_t c6_region[8]; /* MPU base/size registers.  */
   uint32_t c6_insn; /* Fault address registers.  */
   uint32_t c6_data;
   uint32_t c9_insn; /* Cache lockdown registers.  */
   uint32_t c9_data;
   uint32_t c13_fcse; /* FCSE PID.  */
   uint32_t c13_context; /* Context ID.  */
   uint32_t c13_tls1; /* User RW Thread register.  */
   uint32_t c13_tls2; /* User RO Thread register.  */
   uint32_t c13_tls3; /* Privileged Thread register.  */
   uint32_t c15_cpar; /* XScale Coprocessor Access Register */
   uint32_t c15_ticonfig; /* TI925T configuration byte.  */
   uint32_t c15_i_max; /* Maximum D-cache dirty line index.  */
   uint32_t c15_i_min; /* Minimum D-cache dirty line index.  */
   uint32_t c15_threadid; /* TI debugger thread-ID.  */
   } cp15;
   ```

`*` I'm not sure of the exact location, just some guesses based on [qemu/gdbstub.c](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/qemu.git/tree/gdbstub.c), but I'm not able to actually test it.